# Detecting 5 in a row

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making a game of tic tac toe 5 in a row. I have the grid where whenever you click on a square, it records a "coordinate" of [row,column] in the certain color of the dot. I'm currently not sure how to use the 'coordinates' to detect a five in a row of either color and just prints out a message.

Note: If 5 in a row gets tedious with the copy and pasting of previous code or such, a 3 in a row will also work for me and I will just modify it into a 5 in a row. Also when viewing the code snippet below, use the full screen mode.

Code I have so far:

```js
var white=true;
function generateGrid( rows, cols ) {
    var grid = "<table>";
    for ( row = 1; row <= rows; row++ ) {
        grid += "<tr>"; 
        for ( col = 1; col <= cols; col++ ) {      
            grid += "<td></td>";
        }
        grid += "</tr>"; 
    }
    return grid;
}

$( "#tableContainer" ).append( generateGrid( 10, 10) );

$( "td" ).click(function() {
   $(this).css('cursor','default');
   var index = $( "td" ).index( this );
   var row = Math.floor( ( index ) / 10) + 1;
   var col = ( index % 10) + 1;
   var $td = $(this);
   if ($td.data('clicked')) 
      return;
      if (white===true){
          var whi=[row,col];
          console.log("white coord is "+whi);
      } else {
          var bla=[row,col];
          console.log("black coord is "+bla);
      }

   $td.data('clicked', true);

   $td.css('background-color', white ? 'white' : 'black');
   white = !white;
});
```

```css
html{
    background-color:#7189ea;
}
td {
    border: 1px solid;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    border-radius:100%;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="tableContainer"></div>
```

Comment: Store the locations as a 2D array. When a user clicks on a square check the indexes in the array of the row (x + N)/column (y + N)/diagonal(x + N, y + N) for 5 matching colours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've written a function that checks whether the last move wins the game. It basically loops the squares in every direction (and backwards) and looks for 5 in a row (the required length of a line).

```js
var board = new Array();
var boardSize = 5;
var requiredLineLength = 5;
for (var r = 0; r < boardSize; r++) {
    board[r] = new Array();
    for (var c = 0; c < boardSize; c++) {
        board[r][c] = 0;
    }
}

var lineDirections = [
    [0, 1], //horizontal
    [1, 0], //vertical
    [1, -1], //diagonal 1
    [1, 1] //diagonal 2
];

//example usage:
board[0][0] = 1;
board[1][0] = 1;
board[2][0] = 1;
board[3][0] = 1;
board[4][0] = 1;

console.log(checkWin(1, [0, 0]));

// an empty square is marked with 0
// the players are marked with 1 and 2
// pl is the id of the player: either 1 or 2
// lastMove is an array of size 2, with the coordinates of the last move played, for example: [3, 1]
function checkWin(pl, lastMove) {
    var boolWon = false;
    for (var i = 0; i < lineDirections.length && !boolWon; i++) {
        var shift = lineDirections[i];
        var currentSquare = [lastMove[0] + shift[0], lastMove[1] + shift[1]];
        var lineLength = 1;

        while (lineLength < requiredLineLength && legalSquare(currentSquare) && board[currentSquare[0]][currentSquare[1]] === pl) {
            lineLength++;
            currentSquare[0] += shift[0];
            currentSquare[1] += shift[1];
        }

        currentSquare = [lastMove[0] - shift[0], lastMove[1] - shift[1]];
        while (lineLength < requiredLineLength && legalSquare(currentSquare) && board[currentSquare[0]][currentSquare[1]] === pl) {
            lineLength++;
            currentSquare[0] -= shift[0];
            currentSquare[1] -= shift[1];
        }
        if (lineLength >= requiredLineLength)
            boolWon = true;
    }
    return boolWon;
}

function legalSquare(square) {
    return square[0] < boardSize && square[1] < boardSize && square[0] >= 0 && square[1] >= 0;
}
```

It's not fully tested so let me know if you encounter any problems or if you need any clarification on how this works.

Comment: Can you please put it into a code in a snippet please! You can use the code that I provided above and place your code somewhere in there.

Comment: @SuhanGui I'm not sure how my code interacts with yours. You can simply import it in script tag and debug it. Just play with the values you enter the board variable to understand how it works (under the "example usage" comment).

Comment: I put the code in a snippet for your comfort :)
It only logs the boolean result of checkWin though.

Comment: Ohhh I understand the code now. I misunderstood the code at first. Now it makes sense to me what you did.